# Is it possible to drop event notification on database drop (or when it is overwritten by backup)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So, I've [created event notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-event-notification-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the server (for server-related messages), the command is something like that:

```
create event notification NAME on server for EVENT_NAME to service SERVICE_NAME, 'current database'
```

In general, it works great, but when I drop my database, the conversation between the server and my service become broken (because the service has been deleted as well with a queue). But my event notification is still there (because it was created on the server), so I continue to receive messages that just all stored in ***msdb.sys.transmission_queue*** and the typical message is:

> The Service Broker in the target database is unavailable: 'The service broker is administratively disabled.'.

My idea is to drop that event on db drop, but I have no idea how to do that, and it should work for the case when a backup is applied to the database. Or maybe there is another approach for that case. I'm using MSSQL 2017.

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean automatically drop the server event notification automatically, no, but you can drop it explicitly with `DROP EVENT NOTIFICATION NAME ON SERVER;` when you drop the database. Another approach is a server-level DDL trigger for drop database that drops associated event notifications in `sys.server_event_notifications` .

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks, server-level DDL trigger is what I was looking for (because I want to remove that event automatically). The only problem left is that as for db drop I can use DROP_DATABASE DDL event (and that works well), but I have no idea how could I capture the case when a backup is applied to db (so it cleans db in my case, I mean it removes queues and services).